# using a RadDesktopAlert in a Console Application

Tags: winforms, telerik

I have got a console application that to watch for another process to be alive and otherwise send an email (this is just implemented and working) and show a notification. I've used `MessageBox.Show` but it makes really Win3.1, I was wondering if someone succeeded in using Telerik's \

I've tried with this piece of code but nothing happens (even an exception)

```
        RadDesktopAlert alert = new RadDesktopAlert();
        alert.CaptionText = "Critical Error";
        alert.ContentText = "Some text";
        alert.Show();
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You still need to add a RadDesktopManager

```
RadDesktopAlertManager manager = new RadDesktopAlertManager ();
manager.ShowAlert (alert);
```